# How to show images in music player's background notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, notifications

I am creating a music player in flutter. I used on_audio_query package to fetch local songs. In my code, I am using QuertArtworkWidget which takes **id** to show images, so I want to know if, is there any way to get proper image of the song, to pass it to my notification?.

I did not get any method yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.